# Dirichlet-multinomial distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, multinomial-coefficients

I'm reading "Microbiome, Metagenomics, and High-Dimensional Compositional Data Analysis" by Li ([Annual Review of Statistics and Its Application](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-statistics-010814-020351?journalCode=statistics), 2015). There is a part on using Dirichlet-multinomial to model joint-count data that I don't quite follow.

> In addition to scalar summary statistics, such as $\alpha$-and
>   $\beta$-diversity, one can directly model observed taxa count data
>   using Dirichlet multinomial regression (La Rosa et al. 2012, Chen & Li
>   2013b, Holmes et al. 2012). One advantage of this approach is that it
>   automatically accounts for measurement errors and other uncertainties
>   associated with the counts. Suppose we have $p$ bacterial taxa, and
>   their counts $ n = ( {n}_{1}, {n}_{2},..., {n}_{p} ) $ follow a
>   multinomial distribution with probability mass function 
>   $$    {f}_{M}( {n}_{1}, \dots, {n}_{p}; \phi) = \binom{ {n}_{+} }{ n } \prod_{j=1}^{p}{ {\phi}_{j}^{ {n}_{j} } },  
> $$
>   where $ {n}_{+} = \sum_{ j=1 }^{ p }{ {n}_{j} } $ and $\phi = ({\phi}_{1}, {\phi}_{2}, \dots, {\phi}_{p} )$ are underlying species proportions for which $\sum_{ j=1 }^{ p }{ {\phi}_{j} } = 1$.

Okay, here I don't get what is $n$ in the binomial coefficient. Moving further...

> For microbiome composition data, the observed variation is usually
>   larger than what would be predicted by the multinomial model. This
>   increased variation results from the heterogeneity of the microbiome
>   samples and from variation among samples in the underlying
>   proportions. To account for the extra variation or overdispersion, we
>   assume the underlying proportions are themselves positive random
>   variables $ ( {\Phi}_{1}, {\Phi}_{2}, \dots, {\Phi}_{p} ) $, subject
>   to the constraint $ \sum_{ j=1 }^{ p }{ {\Phi}_{j} } = 1$. This
>   assumption implies that the underlying proportions follow a Dirichlet
>   distribution $ Dir( {\gamma}_{1}, {\gamma}_{2}, \dots, {\gamma}_{p} )
> $. The counts then marginally follow a Dirichlet-multinomial (DM)
>   distribution, 
>   $$  {f}_{DM}( {n}_{1}, \dots, {n}_{p}; \gamma ) =
> \binom{ {n}_{+} }{ \mathbf{y} } \frac{ \Gamma( {n}_{+} + 1 ) \Gamma(
> {\gamma}_{+} ) }{ \Gamma( {n}_{+} + {\gamma}_{+} ) }  \prod_{ j=1 }^{
> p }{ \frac{ \Gamma( {n}_{j} + {\gamma}_{j} ) }{ \Gamma( {\gamma}_{j} )
> \Gamma( {n}_{j} + 1 ) } } 
> $$
>   To relate a $q$-dimensional covariate vector $ \mathbf{Z} = ( {z}_{1}, {z}_{2}, \dots, {z}_{q} ) $ to taxa composition, we assume that the parameters $ {\gamma}_{j} $ in the DM model depend on the covariates via a log-linear model
>   $$
> {\gamma}_{j} (\mathbf{Z}) = \exp \left ( {\alpha}_{j} + \sum_{k=1}^{q}{ {\beta}_{jk} {z}_{k} } \right ),
> $$
>   where $ {\beta}_{jk} $ measures the effect on the $j$-th taxon of the $k$-th covariate.

Here I don't get what is $ \mathbf{y} $. I suppose $ {\gamma}_{+} $
is the sum over $ \gamma $, though the author doesn't state it explicitly. The author says nothing about $\alpha$ either. In both cases I suppose that the author uses the notation for binomial coefficient to actually represent multidimensional slices of $p-1$-dimensional Pascal simplex. Am I right?